# Mongodb OR then countDocument mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have a query I am running at the moment which allows me to allow a business to show up if a person is within 10km.

However I want to add the ability to also show people if the user is inside a polygon.

I want to be able to do both queries at the same time in one query.

```
db.geom.insert({
  "polygons": {
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [ 17.60083012593064, 78.18557739257812],
      [ 17.16834652544664, 78.19381713867188],
      [ 17.17490690610013, 78.739013671875],
      [ 17.613919673106714, 78.73489379882812],
      [ 17.60083012593064, 78.18557739257812]
    ]]
  }
});
```

To do the polygon query I can do this.

```
db.geom.find({
  polygons: {
    $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [17.3734, 78.4738]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I currently have a query that does this.

```
 advertquery = { location:{ $geoWithin:{ $centerSphere: [ [ parseFloat(docs.location.coordinates[0]), parseFloat(docs.location.coordinates[1])], 10 / 6378.1] } } };
                                                     
                                                          
 //START COUNT
 var adquery = GEMS.countDocuments(advertquery).exec(function(err, count){
                                                           
 adcount = count
 });
```

To get these two queries to work I have had to write this code.

```
advertquery =   {
 $or: [
                                                                 {location:{
                                                                    $geoIntersects: {
                                                                      $geometry: {
                                                                         "type": "Point",
                                                                         "coordinates": [17.3734, 78.4738]
                                                                       }
                                                                    }
}
},
{ location:{ 
                                                                    $geoWithin:{ 
                                                                      $centerSphere: [ [ 17.3734, 78.4738], 10 / 6378.1] } } }
      ]
                                                             
}
                                                        


                                                          
//START ADCOUNT
                                                          var adquery = GEMS.countDocuments(advertquery).exec(function(err, count){
if(err){console.log(err)}
                                                            console.error("TOTAL COUNTED : "+count);
   adcount = count
});
```

However the countDocuments is not returning the count, just 0.

But when I run this is compass I get 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

From the [mongodb](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#countDocuments) / [mongoose](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#countDocuments) documentation, it states countDocuments() does not support certain operators, that includes `$geoWithin` that you have used in the above query but can be replaced as mentioned in the docs.